# R table() output to csv file

Tags: r, write.table

I use R funtions, table() and write.table(), seprately to count cells number and save to local direction as .csv file.
But there are 2 questions:

1. the title of the generated table is a set of the month, but the rank is according to the initial letter, not the calendar month order.
   I understand that one solution is to factorize the month, but, the data include more than 40 months.
   So, are there any alternative solutions?
2. the generated table title length is one less than the table width, therefore, in .csv file, the title is not right for its column but the next column.

```
TabCDY <- table(DayNobyCounter$CounterID, DayNobyCounter$Year)
write.table(TabCDY, file = "Tab_CounterDayNumber_Year.csv", sep = ",", quote = FALSE, row.names = TRUE )
```

[image: the output for a .csv file]

Answer (score 2):

You may find it easier to work with a `data.frame` (or its cousins like `data.table`) in this case.

The number of months shouldn't matter for the factorization, since the sorting should be done automatically.

Sample data:

```
library(data.table)
NN = 1e5
set.seed(39439)
DT = data.table(
  CounterID = sample(LETTERS, NN, TRUE),
  # integer values of 2019-01-01 -> 2019-12-31
  date = format(.Date(sample(17897:18261, NN, TRUE)), '%Y %b')
)
```

You might try:

```
# old approach
table(DT$CounterID, DT$date)

# suggested approach
levels = unique(DT$date)
# %Y %b is not enough for as.Date, we have to manually supply the day too
levels_date = as.Date(paste(levels, '01'), format = '%Y %b %d')
# sort by the order as a Date (i.e. chronologically)
levels = levels[order(levels_date)]
# levels determines the sorting order
DT[ , date := factor(date, levels = levels)]
# dcast automatically uses this sorting order
TabCDY = DT[ , dcast(.SD, CounterID ~ date, fun.aggregate = length)]
#output to file
fwrite(TabCDY, 'Tab_CounterDayNumber_Year.csv')
```